# What is the smallest video size possible in Sony Vegas Pro?

Tags: video, vegas-pro, compression-data

What is the smallest video size possible in Sony Vegas Pro?

I have a 2.21 GB 40 hour long video I need to compress as much as possible (preferably 100 MB). I don't care about quality as it is already a `240*144` resolution. I don't care about bitrate or FPS or anything. There is no audio either. I just need it to be REALLY small.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest possible output is 0 bytes.  Simply delete the video.  Otherwise, it is going to depend on the bit-rates supported by whatever output format you want to use.  Simply choose an output with the lowest possible bit-rate and number of frames and output.

Trying to get 40 hours in to 100Mb requires a .7kbps data rate though.  You are unlikely to have anything worth watching at that level of compression.

Comment: Doesn't need to be watchable, just a very long video. Sorry if this makes no sense but I'm trying to make the longest video on the internet. I'm going to multiply the 40 hour video by 20 when I'm done.

Comment: In that case, why not make something that goes on forever using something like some flash animation that derives the next frame based on the previous (or based on the amount of time since the video started playing).  It could then literally go on for as long as the user watches it.

Comment: Cool idea AJ Henderson, wonder what it would look like using either a Fibonacci sequence or a pseudorandom sequence?

Comment: Well then see, that's not a "video" but rather a never ending flash player. I'm going for numbers here, like 1200 hours. Thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: I've actually managed to achieve the compression level I want with Adobe Premier but it has this stupid video length limit of 6 hours in the editor so I can't do much else.

Comment: Another idea is to make a 1 pixel by 1 pixel video that plays back a representation of the Bible (or some similarly long book) in Morse code.  At 1 pixel by 1 pixel, you could have a framerate of 2 frames per second.  You'd need a computer program to make the video, but it would encode incredibly small and be incredibly long and actually have meaning while still compressing to something stupidly small.

Comment: `telnet miku.acm.uiuc.edu`

Comment: @mattdm - that is simultaneously both disturbing and awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Since your intentions seem a bit weird, I'll give a weird suggestion; if a video consists largely of a still image, then any decent compression algorithm will use almost no space in storing that length of time. So you'll notice if you go to "watch" a track someone's uploaded to YouTube with only album art for its image, the video loads very quickly.

This depends on whether you can actually change the content of the video, though. Otherwise, you can theoretically tell Vegas to render it at 16px by 9px (or 4px by 3px).